# Sidenav overlay fixed in top right corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys I'm trying to make navigation that is fixed in top right corner comes from right side of the screen (right to left animation). Now using example from w3school I was able to come up with the following code:
HTML:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; </a>
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#">Clients</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

SCSS:

```
#mySidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0; 
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
transition: 0.5s; 
a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}
a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
color: #f1f1f1;
}
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 55px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '300px';
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
}
```

Now the code works fine that not my issue. I would like make my sidenav fixed in top right corner with animation from right to left, every try I made has been and utter failure. So my question is it possible to do this and how would you guys do it ????
Here is the link to the codepen I made so you can see the code in action https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/MpKvXp

Comment: like this? what was an utter failure exactly? Seems like all you need to do is change `left` to `right` for the fixed menu, but I also moved your hamburger icon https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/MpKEWE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `left: 0;` to `right: 0;`.

**Working example:**

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '300px';
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

#mySidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#mySidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}

#mySidenav a:hover,
#mySidenav .offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#mySidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

body {
  height: 200em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<span class="hamburger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still want my hamburger always at top right corner of the screen. To follow the scroll if you understand me.

Comment: Just made an update to my code above. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Partially span should also be in fixed to top right corner

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you!